# Finding out the derivatives through table values.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Question: Suppose that the functions $f$ and $g$ and their derivatives with
respect to x have the following values at $x = 1$ and $x = 2$.[image: Full Question]

My Answer: [Part 1 Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQ2lE.png)
[image]
[Part 2 Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/of0hq.png)[image]

My Problem: My friend said that you have to take out the half from $x/2$ when you derive it. But I don't think that's the proper way to do the chain rule. Who do you think is right over this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When taking derivatives at a point, say $x=2$, it is very important that you only plug in $2$ after taking the derivative.

See for example the first part

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}(f(x/2)g(x))
&=\frac{d}{dx}\Big(f(x/2)\Big)g(x)+f(x/2)\frac{d}{dx}\Big(g(x)\Big)\\
&=f'(x/2)\color{blue}{\frac{d}{dx}\Big(x/2\Big)}g(x)+f(x/2)g'(x)\\
&=\color{blue}{\frac{1}{2}}f'(x/2)g(x)+f(x/2)g'(x)
\end{align}$$

Now we plug in $x=2$ to get the correct answer for part (i). Does this make sense?

Comment: alright. thank you so much. my professor didn't clarify this well enough.

Comment: I made a mistake earlier. Now it is correct!

Comment: Ah I see. now it makes more sense, i was wondering why the x/2 turned into x. thank you once again!